# Equivalence of Permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If a square matrix $B$ is obtained from permutation matrix $A$  by swapping its rows, is it true that $T^{-1}AT=B$ for some invertible $T?$
Appreciate your advice, thank you.

Comment: For a simple counterexample, let $A$ be the identity matrix, which is only similar to itself, because $T^{-1}IT = I$ for any invertible $T$

Comment: No way, its never equal to B, since that will make both the determinants (i.e. det(A) = det(B) and AT = BT) and that's not possible, since swapping them should give you det(B) = - det(A). So, the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

No. If $T^{-1}AT=B$, then $\det(B)= \det(A).$

If $B$ is obtained from $A$ by swapping to rows of $A$, Then $ \det(B)= - \det(A).$